# jQuery: How can I create an object of arrays with variables setting the number of object keys and the key value itself?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, dictionary

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and was hoping you could help.

My goal is to create an `object` of `arrays` where each `key` is set by a `variable` and the `values` of this `key` are a filtered result of another `array`.

Okay, that was complicated to write, here is an example:

```
<!-- Markup -->
<section id="container">
    <article class="class-1">1</article>
    <article class="class-2">2</article>
    <article class="class-3">3</article>
    <article class="class-4">4</article>
    <article class="class-5">5</article>
    <article class="class-6">6</article>
    <article class="class-7">7</article>
    <article class="class-8">8</article>
    <article class="class-9">9</article>
</section>

//  Desired outcome:
//  plugin variables are
    { columns:3 }

var cols = {
    1 : [ $('.class-1') , $('.class-4') , $('.class-7') ],
    2 : [ $('.class-2') , $('.class-5') , $('.class-8') ],
    3 : [ $('.class-3') , $('.class-6') , $('.class-9') ]
};

// my jQuery so far:
// note : columns == 3

var cols =  $.map( $('article','#container') , function(item, i) {
                return {[ i%columns+1 : item ]};
            });
```

How can I achieve what I need here?
What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading,

Jannis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do.  You want the articles to automatically sort into a map of columns on load, right?

I don't think `.map` is going to get you there because it will return an array.  In your desired output you have an object with keys for each column.  I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
var columns = 3;
var cols = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('article','#container').each(function(index, value){
        var col = index%columns + 1;
        if(cols[col] === undefined){
            cols[col] = [$(value)];
        } else {
            cols[col].push($(value));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is __exactly__ what I wanted to create, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How [about like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HqQVR/2/):

```
var mapFunc = function(){ return $(this); },
    articles = $('#container article'),
    info = { columns: 3 },
    cols = {
        '1': articles.filter(':nth-child(3n + 1)').map(mapFunc).get(),
        '2': articles.filter(':nth-child(3n + 2)').map(mapFunc).get(),
        '3': articles.filter(':nth-child(3n + 3)').map(mapFunc).get()
    };
```

Or for a more dynamic approach:

```
cols = {};    
for(var i = 1; i <= info.columns; i++)
    cols[i] = articles
        .filter(':nth-child(' + info.columns + 'n + ' + i + ')')
        .map(mapFunc).get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I prefer RSG's solution in this case but regardless this (especially the second solution) is great and I will keep it in mind for future use. Thanks again.